# Shell script calling passing input to command which expects input from terminal

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am trying to write a script which calls the following command

```
[root@xxxxx imtadmin]# admin tower

-------------------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address=xxxxx-42450, cluster=CLRTY-SA, physical address=xxxxx:45155
-------------------------------------------------------------------

NSA Tower Shell

Usage:

 history                   Show admin shell command history.
 !<command prefix>         Execute a command maching the given prefix                            from the command history.
 refresh                   Wake up monitor thread, to update clients.
 autodiscovery <on|off>    Turn autodiscovery on or off.
 add <host(s)>             Add given host(s) by address.
 remove <host(s)>          Remove given host(s) by address.
 list clients              Print listing of clients.
 list services             Print listing of client services.
 select <address|index>    Select a specific client host by address.
 connect <address> [port]  Connect to a given Select a specific
                           client host by address.
 trace                     Send trace message on multicast channel.
 trace <on|off>            Turn trace listening on or off.
 password <password>       Change password for this session only.
 reset password            Reset password to local machine value.
 group <group>             Change channel group for this session only.
                           (such as CLRTY for listening to PPM
                           broadcasts.)
 reset group               Reset group to local machine value.
 list group                List group members.
 exit|quit                 Exit the tower.
 ?                         Print this message.

> list clients **TERMINAL INPUT***

Discovered Clients:
--------------------------
1) xxxxx.ec2.internal:9091 [xxxxx-20212]
--------------------------
> refresh **TERMINAL INPUT***
> list clients **TERMINAL INPUT***

Discovered Clients:
--------------------------
1) xxxxxx.ec2.internal:9091 [xxxxx-59053]
2) yyyyy.ec2.internal:9091 [yyyyy-20212]
3) zzzzzz.ec2.internal:9091 [zzzzz]
--------------------------
>
```

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn /opt/clarity/bin/admin tower
set timeout -1
expect -re "^>{1}"
send "list clients"
```

My script does call the command admin tower and stops at the prompt > but it doesn't accept input provided by script or input I provide from the terminal (my goal is to provide input from the script).

Comment: not sure if you have to use [tag:tcl]. if you prefer writing shell script you can take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
send "list clients\n"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked. Thanks, @Philippe for hinting I need to add expect after providing input.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn /opt/clarity/bin/admin tower
expect -re "^>"
send "list clients\r"
expect -re "^>{1}"
send "refresh\r"
expect -re "^>{1}"
send "list clients\r"
expect -re "^>{1}"
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, Philippe did more than hinting.

Comment: After you send "exit" you should `expect eof` to allow the admin program to exit gracefully.

Comment: After running each command I return to prompt > should I be using expect eof or expect -re "^>{1}"?

Comment: `expect eof` is for recognizing when the spawned process has ended. If you send a command and expect a prompt, then `expect -re {> $}` (that's another regex to recognize your prompt: an angle bracket and a space at the end of line). I am assuming that you don't expect a prompt after you send "exit.

Comment: That's right, I don't expect a prompt after exit. it exits the admin program.